# "Cannot subscript a value of type '[String]' with an index of type 'String'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to display a dynamically updated array in a label using:

```
for i in result {
    outputLbl.text = result[i].joinWithSeparator("\n")
}
```

However I get the error

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[String]' with an index of type 'String'.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: `result.joinWithSeparator("\n")`

Comment: really no need to iterate over the array, simply use what Leo wrote and drop the for-loop. Just write `outputLbl.text = result.joinWithSeparator("\n")`

Answer (score 2):

Note that when using the loop "header" `for X in Y`, you don't get the *indices* of `Y`, but the actual *elements* of `Y`. Judging from your error, `results` is an array of strings (`[String]`). Hence, `i` in you for loop represents---one by one---the elements in the `String` array `results`.

So, *if* you wanted to access the string elements one by one in the for loop above, you could use the approach in your example:

```
let result = ["Hello", "World"]
for myString in result {
    // use each string element in some manner... 
}
```

However, as you are using the `array` method `joinWithSeparator(..)`, you should use, just as Leo writes in his comment above, this method directly on your array (and not their elements!)

```
let result = ["Hello", "World"]
outputLbl.text = result.joinWithSeparator("\n")
/* Hello\nWorld */
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are doing here is trying to iterate through an array of string and then update a label that is in this case "outputLbl".Here you can do something like this

```
    for i in result {
    //result is array of strings.
    // here i is individual element of result array 
    /*    outputLbl.text = result[i].joinWithSeparator(“\n”)*/
    //instead you can write
    outputLbl.text = i.joinWithSeparator(“\n”)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is as follows:

It seems you are confusing the type of `i`. The variable `result` is of type `[String]` which means it is an array of `String` types. By virtue of being an array, it must be subscripted with an `Int`, not a `String`. So something like `result[0]` or `result[12]` is valid, but something like `result["hello"]` is not valid. The variable `i` here is a `String` because it is a single element in an array of `String` types, which means that effectively, what you're trying to do by saying `result[i]` is something along the lines of `result["hello"]`.

That having been said, the true solution to your problem is that the method `joinWithSeparator(_:String)` is not a `String` method but rather a `Sequence` type method. Which means it should be called on a `Sequence` like an object of type `[String]`. So what you should use is:

```
outputLbl.text = result.joinWithSeparator("\n")
```

Answer (score -2):

What's going on here is the compiler is inferring `i` to be of type `String` since that's what `result` is. You should be more verbose in your naming conventions.

```
for specificString in result {
    outputLbl1.text += "\n\(specifcString)"
}
```

EDITED for correctness.

Comment: result seems to be `[String]`, not `String`  Not to mention `+= +=` probably won't do anything useful, or even compile.

Comment: This now works if you fix the typo ("+= +=" should be "+="). But the other answer is much better anyway.